# MongoDB Query for finding books with same author or at-least one matching category

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to find books with same author or at-least one matching category

My Book Schema is like this.

```js
const bookSchema = new Schema(
    {
      title: {
          type: String,
          required: true
      },
      author:{
          type: String,
          required: true,
      },categories:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Category"
    }]
});
```

I am using this. Its not working.

```js
var moreBooks = await Books.find({
    $or : 
        [
            { 
                author: book.author
            },
            { 
                categories: {
                    $elemMatch: { 
                        $in: book.categories 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Could you edit this question with sample docs & inputs that you're passing in. Why are you using `$elemMatch` that too with `$in` ?

Comment: I need to find the books with either same author or one common category as book "book".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct mongodb query for finding books with same author or at least one matching category. My mistake was using Books in place of Book.